# Какие книги посоветуете прочитать для подготовки к олимпиаде по программированию в 9 классе?

Tags: python, олимпиада

Нужны названия книг для подготовки к ВсОШ по информатике в 9 классе
пример одной задачи:
На прямой расположены стойла, в которые необходимо расставить коров так, чтобы минимальное расcтояние между коровами было как можно больше.

Входные данные

В первой строке в
водятся числа N  (2 < N < 10001) – количество стойл и K  (1 < K < N ) – количество коров. Во второй строке задаются N натуральных чисел в порядке возрастания – координаты стойл (координаты не превосходят 109)

Выходные данные

Выведите одно число – наибольшее возможное допустимое расстояние.

Примеры

входные данные

6 3

2 5 7 11 15 20

выходные данные

9

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95621/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я считаю, что не стоит писать олимпиаду на Python, однако, если вы хорошо умеете оптимизировать свои творения, то Python - классное решение. А так для олимпиады хорошими вариантами будут C, Rust, C++, Java, Pascal. В порядке убывания производительности при расчетах.

---

### Книги

1. "Грокаем алгоритмы" - Адитья Бхаргава
   (https://habr.com/ru/company/piter/blog/323310/)
2. "Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ." - Томас Х. Кормен, Чарльз И. Лейзерсон, Рональд Л. Ривест, Клиффорд Штайн.

Comment: Rust редко поддерживают. Ну и да, Pascal не хуже С. Я бы список чуть по-другому написал. `C + stl, Pascal, Java, другие языки`. Я иногда использовал паскаль, когда нужна была глубокая рекурсия, а опции компиляции накосячили. В Паскале `{$M}` всегда работает) (это если msvc нет).

Comment: Хорошо, что это лично ваше личное и ничем не подкрепленное мнение. Потому что Python является лучшим языком для школьников 9 класса из всех вами перечисленных. C/C++ и Java очень сложные для такого возраста, Pascal смысла учить в 2019 году нет, Rust вообще не может быть в этом списке, потому что этот язык слишком сложный и рано учить школьнику. Комментарий не позволяет прикрепить множество ссылок, поэтому я просто сошлюсь на несколько первых страниц результата поиска в Google по запросу "best programming language for schools".

Comment: @pavel python поддерживется на ВсОШ